# Wordpress - Page - "This site is no longer available."

Tags: wordpress

I have a trouble with my wordpress site now.
If we click a page without login progress, it shows us a message "This site is no longer available."
But if we logged in as admin user, it shows a whole page.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Please provide site link

Comment: Are you sure your page is published?

Comment: Yeah the page is published. [strictlyweddings.com/australia-weddings](http://strictlyweddings.com/australia-weddings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this is an error](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/ms-load.php#L93) that's generated when a blog is deleted from a WordPress multisite installation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but mien is not a multi-site. And I looked at the file, but I am not sure what I should change or fix of it....

Comment: I can't see all pages without login. Really strange

Comment: Looking through the WP codebase, that's the only instance of it. If it's indeed not a multisite, might be a plugin? You could give temporarily renaming the plugins folder a try.

Comment: I checked whole source of the site, but there is only the text in the ms-load.php. But if I change the text, the site still shows us the same text.

Comment: Hi Leland, you're right. It's the multi-site. Should I create new page for another site?

Comment: Yeah, right now it looks like that /australia-weddings was deleted. So you'll either have to restore it from backup if you have one, or just create a new one.